# What is the best way to get parent div in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, parent

My code is like this

```
<div class="a">
     <div class="b">
          <a class="c" href="#"><span class="d"></span></a>
     </div>
</div>
```

and js code is like this

```
$(".d").click(function(){
     var aClass =  $(this).parent().parent().parent(); // to get class "a"
});
```

is there any better way to capture class a ?

Comment: try closest http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Comment: parents() returns an array of matching elements, closets() returns the immediate matching ancestor.

Comment: Often, the use of `parents()` is suggested. This will traverse the DOM hierarchy all the way up to the root of the document, which is often unnecessary, and if your selector isn't precise enough, you're in trouble. `closest()`, as @SnowBlind suggested, is the way to go, as traversal will end upon the first match.

Comment: @jquery404 Please accept one of the correct answers for the people who ask the same question.

Comment: @SnowBlind It's only been 13 minutes, give it some time ;-)

Comment: @Jack Reputation reputation reputation :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [`jQuery.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/):

```
$(this).closest(".a");
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to traverse up the tree until a certain condition is met you want [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/):

```
$(this).closest('.a'); // find first predecessor with class a
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$(".d").click(function(){
     var aClass =  $(this).parents(".a"); // to get class "a"
});
```

use .parents()

Answer (score -1):

Try [`jQuery.parents()`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/):

```
$(this).parents("div.a");
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do ,if you know the class

```
$(this).parents('.a');
```

or

```
 $(this).parents('div:eq(1)');
```

Comment: Someone just got 125 rep I guess :)

Answer (score -1):

What about `$(this).parents(".a")`